# Evaluate a list (coma separated) based on numeric values form a vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup, lookup-tables

two data set, couldn't be more gnarled

first, among plenty of columns there are one with keywords coma separated, aka:

```
Id ---- PLAYER -- KEYWORDS
 1 ---- Jonh ---- futball, waterpolo , tennis
 2 ---- Anna ---- soccer, swiming, running
 3 ---- Marc ---- runnign, waterpolo 
 4 ---- Peter --- running
```

and a "ponderation" table with numeric values for all keywords

```
SPORT-- USE_BALL -- IN_WATER
futball --- 1 --------- 0
waterpolo - 1 --------- 1
tennis ---- 1 --------- 0
swiming --- 0 --------- 1
running --- 0 --------- 0
```

and as a result, I would like yo have a table, with a "SUM" of this caracteristics, aka:

```
Id ---- PLAYER -- PLAY_WITH_BALL --- PLAY_IN_WATER ---- KEYWORDS
 1 ---- Jonh ----------- 3 ---------------- 1 --------- futball, waterpolo , tennis
 2 ---- Anna ----------- 1 ---------------- 1 --------- soccer, swiming, running
 3 ---- Marc ----------- 1 ---------------- 1 --------- runnign, waterpolo 
 4 ---- Peter ---------- 0 ---------------- 0 --------- running
```

what would be the aproach ?
preferable without macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another shorter formula option,

In `K2`, formula copied right to `L2` and all copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$2:$E$6,$M2))*F$2:F$6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`FILTERXML` could be of great use here, for example:

[image]

Formula in `K2`:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(F$2:F$6,$E$2:$E$6,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($M2,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

Drag one right and further down.

**Note1**: In versions other than ExcelO365 this would need to be array entered, however in any such case just swap `SUM` for `SUMPRODUCT`.

**Note2**: `FILTERXML` is available from Excel 2013 onwards.